# how to retain user selected column width in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a windows application , and i use datagridview to show the data from database , when user sees the data he will change the width of columns , and closes the application while opening next time the column width will set to default style how to retain user entered width .

Comment: ... And your your question is? And your code is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind datagridview with its column width changed event [ColumnWidthChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnwidthchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of datagridview and sets each column width in Setting(easiest way to store user setting value). Later when loading `datagridview` again, get the width stored in the setting and set in respective column.

You can bind with column changed event :

```
void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender,
    DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Column1= dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width;
    // Set the width of every column of datagridview here
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();// Save setting after setting all column width
}
```

Now, you can use that setting while loading `datagridview`:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = Properties.Settings.Default.Column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a few different ways, the most common and quickest would be to use the `ApplicationSettingsBase`. To see an example, please see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474142/Saving-and-loading-all-control-values-to-user-sett) as it is very detailed in what you want to do. A few other ways include .XML, ApplicationConfiguration file, registry (not recommended - only for application settings), a file or store these preferences into a database and retrieve them who ever the logged in user is.

You haven't mentioned how users are accessing your application, therefore it's a guess for me and anyone else to answer this as this is important to give you the correct guidance in storing and accessing this information.

On another note, I would use XML personally if you are not using a database for the users. The classes for XML are great in .Net and can quickly be wrapped up in a class to read/write your settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OnFormClosing event; for example:

```
Private Sub onformclosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.OnFormClosing
    Dim x As Integer = DataGridView1.ColumnCount
    Dim widths As Integer()
    For i As Integer = 0 To x Step 1
        widths(i) = DataGridView1.Columns(i).Width
    Next
End Sub
```

You could then write the values of widths() to a configuration or settings file. You would also have to write the column count (in my example, the variable x) so that you would be able to recreate the number of columns. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

There's a few different ways but the easiest is to handle the Closed (or Closing) event for the Form and save each width to the built in Settings file.

You can then "restore" those widths in the initialize method for the Form.